# If $AA^T=(BC)(BC)^T$, can I say that there exists a $D$ such that $A=DC$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given 3 real, finite-dimensional matrices A, B, and C such that $AA^T=(BC)(BC)^T$, does it imply that there exists a matrix D such that $A=DC$?

Comment: What is $A^{\prime}$. Are these linear. Is this finite dimensional etc. we need way more details. Until then, I'm voting to close

Comment: You mean "Can I find a $B_1$ such that $A=B_1C$"? Or do you mean, also with another $C$?

Comment: @AndresMejia Added the details that you requested. Thanks.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm asking if that is implied by the given statement.

Comment: So, your question is "Given three real matrices $A,B,C$ such that $AA'=(BC)(BC)'$, does this imply there exist a matrix $D$ such that $A=DC$"?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this does not need to be true.  An easy way to find counterexamples is to take $B = I$ and find a singular matrix that factors non-uniquely.

Here's such a counterexample.  Take

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So that $$A A^T = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = I \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \left(I \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\right)^T$$

But clearly it's not possible that $$\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = D\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ since the upper right entry of the right-hand-side is going to be zero no matter what $D$ is.